# Completely disable mnemonics systemwide in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to remap several keybindings to resemble those of MacOS, but it seems like the systemwide mnemonics are overriding the keybindings that I want. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be very easy, but start by redefining any keyboard combination exposed in the Settings - Keyboard dialog to nothing, or at least directly to the binding you would prefer. Other definitions of keybindings will be stored in dconf-editor, and in the case of Ubuntu 16.04 in Compiz-config-settings (which, however, may also be in dconf), so looking there you should be able to find most if not all of the bindings you want to change.